# Simple ODE with substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial-value problem $t(\frac{dy}{dt})=y+\sqrt{t^2+y^2}$,$y(1)=0$

I try to let $v=\frac{y}{t}$

Then the DE reduces to $t(\frac{dv}{dt})=\sqrt{1+v^2}$

Which becomes $t^2=y+\sqrt{t^2+y^2}$

Then if we look back to the original ODE, this becomes $t(\frac{dy}{dt})=t^2$

But the solution is actually $y=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$

What's wrong with my solution? Thank you!

Comment: The first part is fine as far as $tv'=\sqrt(1+v^2)$. Integrating that gives $v=\sinh(c+\ln t)$. Applying $y(1)=0$ gives $c=0$, so $v=\sinh\ln t=\frac{t-1/t}{2}$ and hence $y=\frac{t^2-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y(t) = t v(t)$. I'm writing $v$, but remember it is still a function of $t$.

So,

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = v(t) + t \frac{dv}{dt}$$

This implies

$$t(t \frac{dv}{dt} + v) = \sqrt{t^2+t^2v^2}+tv$$

Simplify

$$t(t \frac{dv}{dt} + v) = t (\sqrt{v^2+1} + v)$$

Solve for $\frac{dv}{dt}$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{v^2 +1}}{t}$$

Divide by $\sqrt{v^2 + 1}$

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2+1}}\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{t} $$

Integrate both sides, and we can easily evaluate the integrals - both are standard integrals

so,

$$ \sinh^{-1}{v}= \ln{t} + C$$

Where $C$ is a constant. Now solve for $v$

$$ v = \sinh{( \ln{t} + C)} $$

Use initial conditions $y(1) = 0$

So

$$ y = t (\sinh{C + \ln{t}}) $$

Then, $ \sinh{C} = 0$, thus $C = 0.$

Now, $$y = t ( \sinh{( \ln{t})}) $$, but $\sinh{(\ln{t})}$ can be simplified to $\frac{t^2-1}{2t}$ using $\sinh{x} = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

So $$\sinh{(\ln{x})} = \frac{e^{\ln{x}}-e^{\ln{(1/x)}}}{2} = \frac{x-e^{\ln(1/x)}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{x-1}{x}$$ 
So,

$$ y = t ( \frac{t^2-1}{2t}) ,$$

$$y = \frac{t^2-1}{2} $$

As required.

Comment: $$\frac{A}{B} use this.